# Make elements touch each other with no vertical gaps

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

I have some elements here in a grid.

[image]

However I would like the letters and numbers to be touching each other. With no gap between them.

Something like this:

[image]

The code at the moment looks that this:

In JSX but works the same as HTML.

```
  <ul className='week-forecast-list'>
        <li className='week-forecast-item'>
          <h3 className='week-forecast-day'>
            {formatDateToDay(list[0].dt_txt)}
          </h3>
          <h4 className='week-forecast-temp'>
            {formatTemp(list[0].main.temp)}
            <span className='degrees-icon'>º</span>
          </h4>
          <p>{list[0].weather[0].main}</p>
</li>
</ul>
```

```css
.week-forecast-list {
  display: grid;
  gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(180px, 1fr));
}
.week-forecast-item {
  border: 1px solid var(--darkish);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.week-forecast-day {
  font-size: 8rem;
}
.week-forecast-temp {
  font-size: 8rem;
}
```

Comment: Can you post your actual HTML code?

Comment: Without seeing the code, I'm going to confidently assume that you're wanting to make the `gap: 10px` 0px.

Comment: Apologies, I have updated. It's in JSX for works the same as html if you're unfamiliar.

Comment: Try `margin:0;` on `<h3>` and `<h4>`

Comment: There is no margin on the elements.

Comment: The area taken up is purely content.

Comment: when you say content, do you mean your font's are too big and spilling over?

Comment: In the inspector using the box model only the content is present. I have a feeling your'e on the right track with that the fonts are spilling over. Is there a way to have the font this size but have the actually letters themselves touch?

Comment: Whilst keeping semantic meaning.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `line-height` property

```css
line-height: 0.75;
```